# Run-Time Error 13: Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a "Run-Time Error 13: Type Mismatch" on the following macro (debug line is highlighted).  My objective is to check row 1 for any quantity greater than 1 to warn the user that the clock is running for an activity, then exit the macro.  A number in row 1 means the user has started the clock on an activity, but clock can only run for one activity at a time.  I tried using "ON" in row 1...Dim StartOnRow as Text...but I get the same error.  Much appreciation for any help!

```
Sub StartRunningTimer()
        Dim StartOnRow As Integer
        **StartOnRow = Range("a1:bj1")**
        If StartOnRow > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Please stop the previously started activity")
        If StartOnRow = True Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Worksheets("TimeElapsed").Activate
    nr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TimeElapsed").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(nr, 1) = Format(Now(), "m.d.yy h:mm:ss")
        If Not Started Then
        myTime = Time
        Started = True
    Else
        Worksheets("TimeElapsed").Cells(1, 1).Value = "ON"
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(64, 2).Value = "PRESS IS RUNNING"
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(65, 2).Value = "Time Started:  " & Format(Now(), "hh:MM:ss")
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(74, 2).Value = ""
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(75, 2).Value = ""
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `Set` statement:

```
Set StartOnRow = Range("a1:bj1")
```

Also, Range returns a Range object, not an integer:

```
Dim StartOnRow AS Range
Set StartOnRow = Range("a1:bj1")
```

Comment: Yeah, this was my first reaction, too, but this doesn't fit with the rest of the OP's code. I have to admit it's really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just anything greater than one in any of those cells just use a helper cell in `BK1` that sums the entire row. Check that cell, `StartOnRow = Range("BK1").Value`

As for your question, @roryap is correct. When using `Range` like that, you're getting an object and need to `set` but that still doesn't get what you want because you would need to loop through the range then to find a value > 1.

```
Dim StartOnRow as Range
Dim cellCheck as Range

Set StartOnRow = Range("A1:BJ1")

For Each cellCheck in StartOnRow
     if cellCheck.value > 1 Then
          'Stop
          'Exit Sub
     End if
Next cellCheck
```